# unable to use/locate sudo

Tags: sudo

I am using ubuntu 12 and am unable to use `sudo` anymore (it was working a few days ago) but apparently got corrupted somehow.  Below is the error I receive when I try using `sudo`.

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Besides reusing the ubuntu live cd, is there anything else I can possibly look into in order to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You can manually create a `sudoers` file like this one:

```bash
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

You can follow [this guide](http://www.garron.me/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html) on how to edit / create the `sudoers` file.

Also, check [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1516112.html).

Comment: I ended up re-installing Ubuntu.  I was not entirely certain if I could place the sudoers file in the correct location without root access (I was getting permission denied errors).  Most likely, an oversight on my side - thank you for responding (+1)